# React-Form(v7) Reactstrap with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-form, react-redux-form, reactstrap

I got typescript acting weird, and need a help to solve it.
I'm trying to use **redux-form(v7)** with **reactstrap**

**Form.tsx**

```
<Field
    type="text"
    component={InputField}
/>
<Field
    type="password"
    component={InputField}
/>
```

**InputField**

```
import {Input} from 'reactstrap';
import {WrappedFieldProps} from 'redux-form/lib/Field';

type Props = {
  type?: string;
}

const InputField = (props: WrappedFieldProps & Props) => {
  const { type, input } = props;
  return(
    <Input
      type={type}
      {...input}
    />
  );
};
```

In that case, I got Typescript error: **TS2322**

```
    Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type '"number" | "select" | "textarea" | "text" | "hidden" | "color" | "email" | "file" | "radio" | "ch...'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"number" | "select" | "textarea" | "text" | "hidden" | "color" | "email" | "file" | "radio" | "ch...'.
```

But if I change `type?: string` to `type?: InputType;` **(** type from reactstrap `import {InputType} from 'reactstrap/lib/Input';` **)** then it fixes the problem in **InputField** but then I get same error in **Form.tsx**

Answer (score 0):

An old question but I was also searching for an answer to this. Some solutions I found:

```
<Input type={"text" as any} />
```

or

```
import { Input } from 'reactstrap';
import { InputType } from 'reactstrap/lib/Input'

let type:InputType = "text"  // You can use Ctrl+Space on VSC for "enum"'d values
<Input type={type} />
```

or

```
import { Input, InputProps, ButtonProps } from 'reactstrap';

type InputElement = {
  [name:string]:InputProps
}
type BtnElement = {
  [name:string]:InputProps
}

let inputElement:InputElement = {

  login: {
    onChange: this.handleChange,
    onKeyDown: this.handleKeydown,
    value: this.state.username,
    type: "text",
    placeholder: "Username",
    name: "username"
  }
}
let btnElement:BtnElement = {
  submitBtn:{
    onClick:() => this.submit(),

  }
}

<Input {...inputElement.login} />
<Button {...btnElement.submitBtn}>Login</Button>
```